# Best way to RaisePropertyChanged on a view model Property from within a UI table cell

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uitextfield, mvvmcross

Here is what I'm trying to do...  On my view model I have the following method:

```
private bool AllValuesFilledIn()
    {
        return Inspection.InspectionValueCategories.All(category => !category.InspectionValues.Any(value => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value)));
    }
```

I then use this method to enable and disable a button that navigates to the next screen.  (i.e. I'm verifying you've filled everything in before you can go to the next screen)  Like so:

```
    public ICommand NextScreenCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(async () => await ExecuteNextScreenCommand(), AllValuesFilledIn); }
    }
```

My problem here is that by default changing this value on the table cell doesn't update the UI tell it to re-enable the button when everything is filled in.  I thought I could accomplish this by having the table cell publish a message that the view model is listening for.  Like so:

Cell:

```
public partial class InspectionCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("InspectionCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("InspectionCell");

    public InspectionCell(IntPtr handle)
        : base(handle)
    {
        this.DelayBind(() => {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<InspectionCell, InspectionValue>();
            set.Bind(DescriptionLabel).To(v => v.Description);
            set.Bind(ValueTextField).To(v => v.Value);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }

    public static InspectionCell Create()
    {
        return (InspectionCell)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();

        ValueTextField.EditingChanged += OnValueTextFieldOnEditingDidEnd;
    }

    private void OnValueTextFieldOnEditingDidEnd(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(new InspectionViewUpdateMessage(this));
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        if (!disposing)
        {
            return;
        }
        var textField = ValueTextField;
        if (textField != null)
        {
            textField.EditingChanged -= OnValueTextFieldOnEditingDidEnd;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class InspectionViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IDisposable updateToken;

    private Inspection inspection;
    public Inspection Inspection
    {
        get { return inspection; }
        set
        {
            inspection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Inspection);
        }
    }

    public ICommand NextScreenCommand
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(async () => await ExecuteNextScreenCommand(), AllInspectionValuesFilledIn); }
    }

    public InspectionViewModel()
    {
        updateToken = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().SubscribeOnMainThread<InspectionViewUpdateMessage>(OnUpdate);
    }

    private void OnUpdate(MvxMessage obj)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Inspection);
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => NextScreenCommand);
    }

    private bool AllInspectionValuesFilledIn()
    {
        return Inspection.InspectionValueCategories.All(category => !category.InspectionValues.Any(value => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value)));
    }
```

This *almost* works...  Every time I attempt to change the value on the cell it does publish my message.. however the problem is that the messenger publish is causing the text to not actually be filled in on the cell.  I click on the cell, I start typing and nothing gets filled in but the event fires.

What am I missing?  Is there a better way to make this happen?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where this is going wrong, but I'm wondering if `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is what you are missing? I wouldn't personally use the messenger for this - I'd just use a ViewModel inherited from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged for each InspectionValueCategory list item, but I guess your solution should work - whatever you profer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Stuart!  I'm not fond of this implementation either so I would prefer to do something different.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "a ViewModel inherited from MvxNotifyPropertyChanged for each InspectionValueCategory list item?". Could you elaborate a little more?  Do you mean you would implement IMvxNotifyPropertyChanged on any view models that interact with the InspectionValueCategory object?  Or do you mean implement IMvxNotifyPropertyChanged on the list item data structure?

Comment: After looking at this more I think this comes down to me not understanding how this NotifyPropertyChange should be flowing.  I've tried implementing MvxNotifyPropertyChanged in my InspectionValue class and changed all of my lists to ObservableCollections but I'm still not seeing anything happen.  What's the best way for a view model to listen for a property change of a child item inside of an observable collection?

Comment: I removed the RaisePropertyChanged(() => Inspection); from the OnUpdate method and this works as expected now.  That being said if anyone can explain a more elegant way to accomplish this I would be all ears as I'm not a big fan of needing the messenger on this.